# How to build a C library for python

Tags: python

I'm building a package with Python 2.7.3 and gcc 4.7.2. Build is scons based and it terminates complaining that it can't find 'C library for python2.7'?

What is this C library and how do I build it?

Comment: To get correct flags for compilation/linking, you could use `python2.7-config` utility.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually called `libpython2.7.a`. If you don't have it on your system, you can build it from source. Download the tarball from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/ and do the usual `./configure; make`.

Comment: I've done that by doing ./configure --enable_shared; make install. I've made sure my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is pointing to libpython2.7.a.But, the error is still prevalent.

Answer (score 0):

Often, packages are split into those parts for use and those parts that are required for development. You probably have those parts for use installed (interpreter, modules), but the libraries for development of modules are missing. Look for a python-dev package.

Comment: I'm using RHEL4 machine. Is python-dev applicable/need for this machine?

Comment: I have never used that particular system, but it sounds right.